# Multidimensional arrays transpose themselves without being asked

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to access multidimensional arrays in slightly different ways I get different results which I do not understand.

when I run:

```py
ells=np.array([1,2,3,4])

check=np.zeros((2,2,2,len(ells)))
print(check[:,:,:,ells<=4].shape)
print(check[0,:,:,ells<=4].shape)
```

I can actually fix this problem by using

```
ells=np.array([1,2,3,4])

check=np.zeros((2,2,2,len(ells)))
print(check[:,:,:,ells<=4].shape)
print(check[0,:,:,:][:,:,ells<=4].shape)
```

however I would like to understand why the first version is wrong.

In the first case I expect to get arrays of shape (2,2,2,4) and (2,2,4) but I get (2,2,2,4) and (4,2,2).

In the second case I get the answers expected, (2,2,2,4) and (2,2,4).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of mixed advanced and basic indexing:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

The two outer indices select size 4, and the two inner slices are added after that:

```
check[0,:,:,ells<=4]
```

The reason given is that there's a potential ambiguity, when advanced indices are separated by slices.  But the case for this ambiguity is weaker when one of the indices is a scalar (that's an old objection).

I'm sure someone could find a duplicate SO.